# Check if names matches in file using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if the names in `NameList` match the names in the example file `John abree`
if it is then it prints all the names that match names in example file, for example `Hello John Hello abree`

```
NameList = ['John', 'abree', 'acacia']
def names(z):
    with open('example.txt') as file:
        for x in range(1, 3):
            if z == str(NameList[x]) in file.read():
                    print("yes")
                    result = r'Its {names[z]}'


print(names('John'))
Result = f'Hello {names("John")}'
Result = f'Hello {names("abree")}'
```

the output is

```
Its None
Its None
```

How do I fix it?
I know it's something difficult to understand but it's just a test for another script

Comment: There is not return statement in the function, you need to add one.

Comment: In your own words, what should the *result of* `names('John')` be? When you do `print(names('John'))`, what do you expect to be printed *by that print call*, not by `names` itself?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The words in `names` function should be printed with the names like this `Hello It's John` or `Hello It's abree`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Do you understand what it means for a function to *return a value*? Do you understand what it means to talk about the *result* of a function? I am *not* talking about printing anything.

Comment: Rephrasing what Karl said: you assign the `result` variable, but don't do anything with it.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you directly, but here are some program flow issues you need to fix:
You need to clarify what your function is attempting to do. Is it going to return `True` if the name is in the file?
As mentioned by others commenting, for a function to return a value, you need to use the `return` statement.
For your code, you are trying to read the entire file 2 times (not 3, range(1, 3) only goes 1 to 2). The second time you call `read()`, it'll get you an empty string.
Arrays in Python are zero-based.

Comment: What is `z` used for? I see you have a list of names already, so your code doesn't match what you are asking it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have commented, and thought about the expressions in your code, and it left me scratching my head. The expression:

`z == str(NameList[x]) in file.read()`

Really confuses me as to its intent. Somehow, you have a list of names, and only check its last 2 entries. Then you have an `in` operator against the entire contents of the file. You say you wanted to print all the names that appear in the file. But if that's the case the way you are using the function is incorrect as well.

This is my stab at understanding your question and seeing what you had.

I think what you wanted to do was something like this.

```
NameList = ['John', 'abree', 'acacia']

def names(in_list):
    with open('example.txt') as file:
        content = file.read():
    for name in in_list:
        if name in content:
            print(f'Hello {name}')


names(NameList)

Hello John
Hello abree
```